# Register receiver without executing application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to have a BroadcastReceiver registered for the BOOT_COMPLETED action. To achieve it, I am using the [receiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) tag inside the manifest file.

It works as expected, but I am wondering if it is possible that this is applied to users when my application is updated. My app already has some users, so I would like that when they update the application this new information on the manifest file is applied, and this receiver is registered without the need for them to actually open my application.

Seems to me it's not working like this, the receiver will be registered next time they open the application, is there any way to have it done? Or more to the actual use case, is there a way to send an android notification after the update?

Comment: If it's in the manifest, it should be registered the moment it's installed and active on the next reboot. Can you confirm that this is **not** working?

Comment: @323go not until an activity has been run.  Its a security check by android-  newly installed apps will not have any services or receivers enabled until the app has had an activity run.  My bet is that it applies to new updates to manifests as well, although I cannot confirm. through testing.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can confirm is that it doesn't work using adb to install the new version... I don't know if there should be any difference when it is updated from the appstore. Also, how do you know it works? Is there any specification of when are this receivers registered? Because I think they may be registered when the application is executed.

Comment: The test would be to install it, reboot and see if it's invoked. I would install through the package manager, not adb -- so place the apk on the device and open it. @GabeSechan seems to be right here, and if you google, there's some more information available. I had never noticed that, as my apps are Activity centric, and the `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver would not be needed unless an interest was declared in the UI.

Comment: @GabeSechan It seems your explanation is what makes more sense. If you want to answer I will mark it as accepted. Do you have any sources for this? Or you know by experience?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18225  This has Dianne Hackborn acknowledging this being added to 3.1 and up.  I don't have any sources on it being recaused on a change to permissions/new receivers.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer, but I faced the same issue. You have to specify the receiver class if you never executed the app before.

So this won't work:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.obaied.myapplication.TEST_ACTION
```

But this would work

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.obaied.myapplication.TEST_ACTION -n com.obaied.myapplication/.TestReceiver
```

Tested it on Android API 25.

Comment: What I was asking was about the app installed on a device from the appstore from a user, not an application installed in my development devices where I have access to running commands

Comment: Ah my mistake then. I must've misunderstood.